# stack size limit and static arrays

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I try to limit stack size to 5096 bytes and pass /STACK:5096 option to linker (VS2010). After compilation I check the binary and the SizeOfStackReserve in optional header is really 5096.

Then I try to test it and write the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

   char a[60000]; // should cause stack overflow
   std::cout << a[59999] // just to be sure, that a is not optimized away
   return 0;
}
```

Why in this case I don't get stack overflow?

Comment: `a` could still be optimised away. Try add `cout << a[59999]`

Comment: How do you know you don't get stack overflow? Writing to random memory beyond the stack won't necessarily cause any noticeable effects.

Comment: Well, I thought there is some guard or invalid page. Am I wrong?

Comment: There might be a guard. It would be checked that it has not been written after return of the function. But there is no write to the array `a` in you function.

Comment: Windows will just ignore excessively small values.  256KB is as low as you'll ever get on current versions, subtract the page guard pages and OS overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I though that stack allocation granularity is equal page size. However, it turned out to be wrong and  granularity on my system (Win7 64bit) is 64Kb. So if lesser stack size is specified, it is ignored.